# When click on button it does not post back

Tags: asp.net, web

I am using a button inside a form, and this from is inside another form. When button is inside the second form its calling directly page load event but not button click event. If I take the button outside the second form nothing will work neither its call page load method nor button click event.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<form class="ak-form" method="post" action="#">

 <ul class="agileits ">
                                            <li class="agileits">
                                                <input required="" id="txtCustMailId" runat="server" class="text-box-dark agileits " type="text" value="Enter Your Email" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter Your Email';}" name="email" /></li>
                                            <li class="agileits">
                                                <input required="" id="txtCustPass" runat="server" class="text-box-dark agileits " type="password" value="Your Password" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Your Password';}" name="password" /></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="ak-btn-cont ak-btn-booking-cont login-btn">
                                            <asp:Button runat="server" class="btn btn-primary agileits button2" CssClass="btn btn-info btnWidth100 btnFont" ID="btnCustLogin" ValidationGroup="CustLogin" Text="Login" OnClick="btnCustLogin_Click" />
                                            <asp:Button runat="server" class="btn btn-primary agileits button2" CssClass="btn btn-info btnWidth100 btnFont" ID="Button2" Text="Forgot Password" OnClick="btnCustLogin_Click1" />


                                        </div>
                                    </form>
</form>
```

Comment: We need some code. Urgently... Really..

Comment: here i added my code sample.you can see over there

Comment: Add backend code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Consolidate the two forms into one form.

```html
<form id="form1" class="ak-form" method="post" action="#" runat="server">
 
</form>
```

If you can't do this because #form1 is wrapping the entire page and in implementation the .ak-form is deeper in the documentation then try adding the runat="server" attribute to the second form element.